# How can I create and manage a Lambda Function from Python Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, build-automation

I would like to manage my AWS Lambda Functions from Python script, without having to use the AWS Website Console. The idea is to be able to quickly recreate/migrate/setup my applications objects (tables, functions etc.) into a new AWS Cloud Account or Region.

It is easy to do this with DynamoDB tables, for instance:

```
import boto3
resource = boto3.resource(service_name='dynamodb', region_name='region', ...)
resource.create_table(
                TableName='table_name',
                KeySchema=[...],
                AttributeDefinitions={...},
                ProvisionedThroughput={...}
            )
```

Done! I just created a new DynamoDB table from Python Script. How can I do the same for Lambda Functions? Say... create a new function, configure ‘Function Name’ and ‘Runtime’, maybe set up a ‘Role’ and upload a script from file. That’d be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create lambda function using boto3, you can use [create_function](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function).

The [AWS docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.create_function) also provide an example of how to use the `create_function`:

```
response = client.create_function(
    Code={
        'S3Bucket': 'my-bucket-1xpuxmplzrlbh',
        'S3Key': 'function.zip',
    },
    Description='Process image objects from Amazon S3.',
    Environment={
        'Variables': {
            'BUCKET': 'my-bucket-1xpuxmplzrlbh',
            'PREFIX': 'inbound',
        },
    },
    FunctionName='my-function',
    Handler='index.handler',
    KMSKeyArn='arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789012:key/b0844d6c-xmpl-4463-97a4-d49f50839966',
    MemorySize=256,
    Publish=True,
    Role='arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/lambda-role',
    Runtime='nodejs12.x',
    Tags={
        'DEPARTMENT': 'Assets',
    },
    Timeout=15,
    TracingConfig={
        'Mode': 'Active',
    },
)

print(response)
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you!

Comment: I put a full example that shows this in context along with some other Boto3 Lambda functions on GitHub, check it out: (aws-doc-sdk-examples)[https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/91b9e57fbbb2d6b6f8ab94284bf04e8e46d1a247/python/example_code/lambda/boto_client_examples/lambda_basics.py#L114].

Comment: @LarenCrawford Thanks for letting me know :-)